# How does the state monad bind into outer context

Tags: f#, state-monad

I am trying to understand the State monad and I am mighty confused I must admit.
I created a Computational Expression and added a lots of print statements so I can follow up who gets called when.

```
type State<'st,'a> =
    | Ok of  'a * 'st
    | Error of string
and StateMonadBuilder() =
    member b.Return(x) = printfn "100 Return %A" x; fun s -> Ok (x, s)
    member b.ReturnFrom(x) = printfn "100 ReturnFrom %A" x; x
    member b.Bind(p, rest) =
        printfn "100 Bind:: %A %A" p rest
        fun state ->
            printfn "200 Bind:: %A %A" p rest
            let result = p state in
            match result with
            | Ok (value,state2) -> (rest value) state2
            | Error msg -> Error msg  

    member b.Get () = 
        printfn "100 Get"
        fun state -> 
            printfn "200 Get :: %A" state
            Ok (state, state)
    member b.Put s = fun state -> Ok ((), s)

let state = StateMonadBuilder()

let turn () =
    state {
        printfn "100 turn::"
        let! pos1 = state.Get()
        printfn "200 turn:: %A" pos1
        let! pos2 = state.Get()
        printfn "300 turn:: %A" pos1
        return! state.Put(fst pos1, snd pos1 - 1)
    }

let move () =
    state {
        printfn "100 move::"
        let! x = turn()
        printfn "200 move:: %A" x
        let! y = turn()
        printfn "200 move:: %A" y
        return x
    }

let run () =
    state {
        printfn "100 run::"
        do! move()
    }

run () (5,5) |> ignore
```

The above code prints the following output

```
100 run::
100 move::
100 turn::
100 Get
100 Bind:: <fun:Get@301> <fun:turn@312>
100 Bind:: <fun:Bind@292-2> <fun:move@322>
100 Bind:: <fun:Bind@292-2> <fun:run@329>
200 Bind:: <fun:Bind@292-2> <fun:run@329>
200 Bind:: <fun:Bind@292-2> <fun:move@322>
200 Bind:: <fun:Get@301> <fun:turn@312>
200 Get :: (5, 5)
200 turn:: (5, 5)
100 Get
100 Bind:: <fun:Get@301> <fun:turn@314-1>
200 Bind:: <fun:Get@301> <fun:turn@314-1>
200 Get :: (5, 5)
300 turn:: (5, 5)
100 ReturnFrom <fun:Put@304>
200 move:: <null>
100 Return <null>
100 Return <null>
```

I understand the first 5 lines of this output. Obviously `run` calls `move` calls `turn` calls `Get`. 
And then there is a `let! pos1 = ...` which triggers the call to `Bind`. So far so good. But then there are additional calls to `Bind`.
How do they come into existence? 
I understand on a superficial level that binding into those outer contexts must be somehow the magic of the state monad but how does this mechanism work?
And then there is another `let! pos2 = ...` in the function `turn` which also triggers `Bind` but this time only once not 3 times as before!

Looking forward to your explainations

Comment: Try looking at the generated desugared code in Reflector or ILSpy.

Comment: actually it is not so much a qquestion about the technical aspect of it - more how is it even possible on a language level to access those outer scopes

Comment: It might be helpful to examine what `<@ state { ... } @>` evaluates to in the cases you're unclear about.  It's not clear to me what additional information would be helpful.

Comment: I am trying to understand how the `state` in `turn` reaches out into its **callers** and retrieves their context (state). Because that is happening as I can see by having 2 additional `Bind` calls.  And I even don't understand how that is possible on a language level as neither `turn` nor `move` nor `run` share a closure. In which case I would understand that behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no magic involved, all smoke and mirrors.

The computation you build up in your workflow is one big function of type `'st -> State<'st, 'a>`. The place where you call `run` is in fact where you apply this function to an initial argument - that's what is passed through the binds and in turn, from the "parent" `move` workflow to `turn`. So it's not that your nested workflow is accessing anything outside - you pass it there yourself instead.

One non-standard choice that you make - that probably doesn't make it easier to understand what is going on - is that your State monad is not a pure state monad, rather it combines aspects of State and Either/Maybe monads (through the Error case of State type). And while you define the State type, your actual monadic type here is the function type I mentioned earlier.

A typical approach would be to define the type as something like this:

```
type State<'st, 'a> = State of ('st ->'a * 'st),
```

i.e. you use a single case union as a wrapper for a function type, or just use the function without the wrapping type. Error handling is typically not a concern state monad deals with.

As for the second part of the question, you do have three binds on your path - `do! move()`, `let! x = turn()` and `let! pos1 = state.Get()` - and this is what you see in the log. I think the sequence in which things happen might be tricky here.

Remember how a bind is desugared:

```
{| let! pattern = expr in cexpr |} => builder.Bind(expr, (fun pattern -> {| cexpr |}))
```

What this means is first you evaluate `expr`, only then `Bind` is called, and finally the rest of computation `cexpr`. In your case, you go "three binds deep" to evaluate the first `expr` - which is the call to `Get()` - then you start resolving your stack of binds, at some point calling another bind as part of the `cexpr`.

It would probably be easier to see what's really going on if you added another print statement after computing `let result = p state` in `Bind`, this is when the bind is being unwound.

Comment: Added some more detail on the "three binds" thing.

Comment: thx. My biggest mental knot was I didnt look into the fact that there are 2 passes. A compile time pass and a runtime pass

Comment: Yes - the nice curly braces syntax is just a code artifact, at compile time it's transformed into a series of builder method calls nested in one another. Note that no code execution happens at compile time, it's a purely mechanical transformation. That's why all the builders follow the same pattern of method names and types - to fit into the transformation process.